# Sort Nokia Here Waypoints

Tags: jquery, here-api

From an web service i am receiving list of randomly selected co ordinates. When i plot them in nokia here and tried to find out the shortest route among them it resulted in a scattered way.

Further drill down shows me those co ordinates are not sorted.

Is there any way to sort co ordinates while transforming them into list of way points or i have to sort all co ordinates before plotting them ? Thanks in advance

code is given below

```
    router = new nokia.maps.routing.Manager();
    var onRouteCalculated = function (observedRouter, key, value) {
        if (value == "finished") {
            var routes = observedRouter.getRoutes();

            //create the default map representation of a route
            mapRoute = new nokia.maps.routing.component.RouteResultSet(routes[0]).container;
            map.objects.add(mapRoute);

            //Zoom to the bounding box of the route
            map.zoomTo(mapRoute.getBoundingBox(), false, "default");
        } else if (value == "failed") {
            alert("The routing request failed.");
        }
    };
    router.addObserver("state", onRouteCalculated);
    var modes = [{
        type: "shortest",
        transportModes: ["car"],
        options: "avoidTollroad",
        trafficMode: "default"
    }];

 function CreateRouteByMultipleWaypoints() {
        if (typeof (mapRoute) != 'undefined' || mapRoute != null) {
            map.objects.remove(mapRoute);
        }
        router.clear();
        var waypoints = new nokia.maps.routing.WaypointParameterList();
        var RUidsByChoice = $('#dialogforPlotRoute').text().trim().split(',');
        for (index = 0; index < selectedcoOrdinatestoPlanRoute.length; index++) {
            waypoints.addCoordinate(new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(parseFloat(selectedcoOrdinatestoPlanRoute[index].split('>')[0]), parseFloat(selectedcoOrdinatestoPlanRoute[index].split('>')[1])));
        }
        router.calculateRoute(waypoints, modes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Travelling Salesman Problem algorithm to find out the shortest path among all given co ordinates

```
function sortWayPoints() {
        var coordinatsArraytoPlot = selectedcoOrdinatestoPlanRoute;
        //Starting location some hard coded value
        var startPoint = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(39.7391500, -104.9847000);
        var mainArray = [];
        mainArray.push(startPoint);
        while (coordinatsArraytoPlot.length > 0) {
            var sortArr = [];
            for (index = 0; index < coordinatsArraytoPlot.length; index++) {
                var coordinate2 = new      nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(parseFloat(coordinatsArraytoPlot[index].split('>')[0]), parseFloat(coordinatsArraytoPlot[index].split('>')[1]));
                var dist = startPoint.distance(coordinate2);
                sortArr.push(dist);
            }
            var test = sortArr[0];
            var lessiNDEX = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < sortArr.length; i++) {
                if (sortArr[i] < test) {
                    test = sortArr[i];
                    lessiNDEX = i;
                }
            }
            // The co ordinates are available in format "lat>long" so i have to 
            //split them and convert them to parseflot to get compatible result
            startPoint = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(parseFloat(coordinatsArraytoPlot[lessiNDEX].split('>')[0]), parseFloat(coordinatsArraytoPlot[lessiNDEX].split('>')[1]));
            mainArray.push(startPoint);
           //Remove calculated co ordinate from main array
            coordinatsArraytoPlot.splice(lessiNDEX, 1);
        }
//mainArray will contain all sorted Co ordinates
}
```